# Is there any reason to back up these system-created certificates?

Tags: sql-server, backup, certificate, encryption

I understand the need for backing up keys and user defined certificates, but is there any reason that we should back up these certificates that are system-created?

### MS_AgentSigningCertificate

### MS_PolicySigningCertificate

### MS_SchemaSigningCertificate34284BF7CE6208DC9D835E9F45ADD94F0757439E

### MS_SmoExtendedSigningCertificate

### MS_SQLAuthenticatorCertificate

### MS_SQLReplicationSigningCertificate

### MS_SQLResourceSigningCertificate

Answer (score 2):

Your first certificate needs to be backed up if you are moving the MSDB between instances.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2000274

In short, its not typically required to explicitly backup those certificates.  Particularly if you are backing up your system databases correctly.